# "The type com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService cannot be resolved" error message

Tags: java, android, google-sheets, google-api-java-client

I got this error message:

> "The type com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files"

I'm using Google API because my goal is to use Google Apps but in Java, especially with Android.

Here's the code :

```
SpreadsheetService service = new SpreadsheetService(" Google Spreadsheet Demo");
       // Login and prompt the user to pick a sheet to use.
        service.setUserCredentials(GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_USERNAME, GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD);
```

The error message is shown when I want to use `service.setUserCredentials` 
I've imported the library of Google API (jars) and even others like `gdata-client/spreadsheets/docs`.